# How to pop from a dict while looping?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following problem. I have a dictionary `dict_a`. I would like to go through it and if some condition is met, then I would like to pop the item from the `dict_a`. When I try this:

```py
for key in dict_a.keys():
     if # some condition:
         dict_a.pop(key)
```

I got an error

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.
```

Is there a more pythonic way how to do it than this below?

```py
dict_b = dict_a.copy()

for key in dict_a.keys():
     if # some condition:
         dict_b.pop(key)  

dict_a = dict_b.copy()
```

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in dict_a.items() if not #some condition}`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a list from `dict_a` keys beforehand:

```
for key in list(dict_a):
     if # some condition:
         dict_a.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You can define your own logic using a regular function or a lambda function, if you wish.

```
def custom_filter_logic(item):
    # if some_condition, return False
    # define your logic below
    k, v = item[0], item[1]
    return v < 3

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in filter(custom_filter_logic, dict_a.items())}
```